# upgrading SharePoint 2007 master page to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2007, master-pages, sharepoint-2010

I am getting ready to upgrade a SharePoint 2007 Master page to a SharePoint 2010 master page. Does anyone have any experience doing this? I could use some suggestions on how to finish the upgrade smoothly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out: [Upgrading an Existing Master Page to the SharePoint Foundation Master Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539981(office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I found the same link.